Confusion about IV-2sls with endogenous interaction term
I am conducting an IV regression where I have one endogenous variable X1 and its interaction with an exogenous variable X2, denoted as X1X2. I have instruments Z1 for X1 and Z2 (which is Z1*X2) for the interaction term. In stata I use the following code: ivreg Y X2 (X1 X1X2 = Z1 Z2) .
In the first stage regression where X1 is the dependent variable, the Z1 is statistically significant but Z2 is not. In the regression where X1X2 is the dependent variable, the Z2 is statistically significant but Z1 is not.
Please help me to understand, is this acceptable or should I be concerned about the insignificance of one instrument in each regression?
Thank you
P.s. the hausman test and the F-statistics are above 10.
